# Problems with static files Go-Echo-Templ

Tags: go, go-templates, go-echo

I am starting a Go project using Echo and Templ.

I have a project structure as follows:

```bash
/
/cmd
    main.go
/static
    css
        style.css
/view
    /layout
        base.templ
```

The problem I am experiencing is that I don't seem to be able to include a stylesheet.

My main. go is as follows:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/RollingITGuy/go-rerun-dist/handler"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func main() {

    app := echo.New()
    app.Static("/static", "static")
    handler := handler.IndexHandler{}

    app.GET("/", handler.HandleShowIndex)

    err := app.Start(":5150")
    if err != nil {
        apperr := fmt.Errorf("server start failed; %w", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%+v\n", apperr)
    }

    os.Exit(0)
}
```

The Templ file is:

```golang
package layout

templ Base() {
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css" />
            <title>Here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            { children... }
        </body>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </html>
}
```

When I view the page source I get:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
```

When I click the link to the stylesheet I receive:

```json
{"message":"Not Found"}
```

What am I missing? What can I fix?

Comment: How are you starting the application? My guess would be that the working directory is `/cmd` whereas your paths assume it's the root folder (you can check this with [`os.Getwd()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Getwd)).

Comment: Brits, I want to make sure I'm understanding correctly.  In the main.go file based on what you're saying I would need to adjust the app.Static("/static", "static") path?  or the <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css" /> relative to where the program is being run?

Comment: What I'm saying is that your program makes an assumption about the current working directory. If you start a terminal and `cd cmd` and then run your app (`./cmd`) it will not work because it's trying to retrieve `static/css/style.css` and, as this is relative to the working directory, the full path would be `cmd/static/css/style.css` (which does not exist). There are a number of ways to fix this (run from the project root i.e. `cmd/cmd`, change the working directory in the app, embed the templates in the executable etc).